# best Jdbc Item reader for large table

Tags: spring-batch

I'm currently building an etl pipeline that pulls data from large oracle tables to mongodb, i want to know exactly what's the difference between **JdbcCursor Item reader** and **Jdbc Paging item reader**. which one of them is best suited for large tables. are they **thread safe** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JdbcCursorItemReader` uses a JDBC cursor (`java.sql.ResultSet`) to stream results from the database and is *not* thread-safe.

`JdbcPagingItemReader` reads items in pages of a configurable size and is thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what is the best for etl use case where pulling from large table ?

Comment: I would start with the cursor-based reader in a single-threaded step. If the performance does not meet your requirement, you can then switch to the thread-safe paging reader in a multi-threaded step.

Comment: OK, definitely i will do that,  mentioning the performance, is it true that using reflection beans would affect performance ? if yes, is there a way to replace them ?

Comment: Yes, reflection-based mappers (like the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`) might have some performance cost. If you want to avoid the reflection cost, create your custom mapper.